# H3 Element not inheriting parent width in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a div with a class of 'screenshot' (in pink), and inside it is an image element and a heading element (in blue). As you can see in the image below; the h3 tag is not being contained by its fixed width parent. How can I contain the heading element inside the parent div so it's width is the same? Specifying width, margin, padding etc. doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="screenshot"><a href="#">
<img src="img/vert_img1.png" alt="Image description">
<h3>Heading #1</h3>
</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#screenshots .screenshot
{
    background: pink;
    width: 209px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.screenshot a img
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.screenshot a h3
{
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 209px;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Stack Overflow uses Markdown. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help - I've fixed your question for you.

Comment: Also bear in mind that it's invalid to have an `<h3>` within an `<a>`.

Comment: not to niggle, but unless you're using HTML5 spec, _technically_ you're not supposed to wrap a block-level element with an anchor tag.

Comment: @Walker Even if we are talking about HTML5 you should still avoid this because browsers without a HTML5 parser (Firefox 3.6 etc.) may still experience problems with this

Comment: Please make an example of your code using [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com). I think you might have missed a few relevant things out in your question, doing that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpb98/) fix the problem you have?

I have fixed the markup, as I notice that other comments have already highlighted, since it is not valid to have an `h3` (or any block level element) inside an `a`.

Comment: Cheers for the fix, great site too - I'll start using it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the h3 to a span, and give it a class. You cannot have an h3 inside an 'a'.

```
span.whateverclass {
    display: block;   
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0;  
}
```

you shouldn't need to give it a width as the total width of a block element is the width of its enclosing block (basically). It's possible in your above example another element is giving h3 its width.

Also

```
a, img  {  
display:block;  
}
```

may help.

Comment: I did end up changing the h3 to a span - worked good after that! Thanks!

Comment: The best way to say thanks on this site is to click the arrow above the numbers :-) Do that for the answer you accepted too!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply taking the hardcoded width off the h3 definition?

You aren't explicitly removing padding so it's really 291px + the default padding the browser implements on the element which is  probably the reason why it's outside the bounds of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help guys, I made the rookie mistake of putting a block element inside an inline. Is it okay to place more than one inline element inside an anchor tag?

Here's what I ended up with:

```
<div class="screenshot">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/2_graphic.jpg" alt="Graphic Design">
        <span>GRAPHIC DESIGN</span>
    </a>                
</div>
```

```
#screenshots .screenshot
{
    width: 209px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.screenshot a img
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.screenshot a span
{
    font-size: 90%;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```